# How to create a Web Server for asynchronous request from a Flex/Air client?

Tags: apache-flex, jakarta-ee, webserver, rpc, blazeds

I have created a client with Flex Builder which works in a browser but also in an Air windowed application. I must connect it to a server and it has to do asynchronous request related to changing data of the server. Because of the too much expensive cost of LiveCycleDS license, I was looking for other ways, maybe open source and i found the following solutions:

- Adobe BlazeDS
- Granite Data Services
- WebORB Community Edition

I want to ask you which is the easy way to create the solution described above, expecially i want to use J2EE application server type.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to connect to a server (XML, SOAP, AMF, etc).  I'd recommend AMF through one of the products you mentioned.  Give each of them a try and see which one works best for you.  Also you can see some code samples in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour).  And you can watch [a screencast](http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2008/07/21/video-flex-and-java/) I did that walks through how to use BlazeDS.